# convert 2015 Trek fx 7.4 from shimano 3x 9speed to sram rival 1

Tags: hub

My rear hub is a Shimano rm30 alloy hub. I want to put a Sram Rival 1 drivetrain 42t .1x 11speed with a srm pg1130 11-36 cassete. what do I replace the Shimano hub with? Does the whole wheel need replaced?

Answer (score 1):

The PG1130 11-36 will go on your hub without having to replace it or do anything to it.